# Getting permission denied when I attempt cp ExampleTxt /home

Tags: command-line

I am a student in college for CS and a new user of linux.

Regarding the question I am simply trying to copy ExampleTxt from from my directory Test_Directory to home. The exact command I am using is "cp ExampleTxt /home" and my CWD is /home/cslinux/Test_Directory. The error line I am getting reads "cp: cannot create regular file '/cslinux': Permission Denied"

Comment: `Permission Denied` this means you don't have sufficient permissions.  `/home/youruser` is your home folder not `/home` which is the directory under which all user's home folders are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/home" is a directory which contains all users' home directories (much like Users folder in Windows). As mentioned by Nmath in the comments, normally only the admin has permission to alter any files in there. *Your* "home directory" is actually /home/cslinux, assuming your username is cslinux.

The closest, most easily doable thing to what you are attempting is achieved by:

```
cp /home/cslinux/Test_Directory/ExampleTxt /home/cslinux/
```

This copies ExampleTxt to the /home/cslinux directory instead. Notice I used an absolute path for ExampleTxt so that the command works independently of the directory you are in.

Also, an alternative way to write /home/cslinux would be "~". Using that, the above command can be shortened to this one:

```
cp ~/Test_Directory/ExampleTxt ~/
```